# How can I send the data from fluentd in kubernetes cluster to the elasticsearch in remote standalone server outside cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I have three kubernetes cluster environments set up in GCP. 
I have installed Fluentd as daemonset in all these environments to collect the logs from all the pods. 
I have also installed elasticsearch and kibana in a separate server outside the cluster. 
I need to feed the logs in fluentd to the elasticsearch in remote server and thereby run a centralised logging platform.

How can I send the data from fluentd to the elasticsearch in remote server?

The error received is:

> error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchOutput::ConnectionFailure error="Can not reach Elasticsearch cluster

Comment: Can't you set `FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST` to an external IP or name?

Answer (score 2):

There are two common ways mentioned in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to access external resources from inside the Pod:

1. Create a Service and Endpoint objects. Set external IP address in Endpoint's specification:

   ```
   kind: Service
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: ext-elastic
     namespace: default
   spec:
     ports:
     - protocol: TCP
       port: 80
       targetPort: 9200
   ---
   kind: Endpoints
   apiVersion: v1
   metadata:
     name: ext-elastic
     namespace: default
   subsets:
     - addresses:
         - ip: 1.2.3.4
       ports:
         - port: 9200
   ```

> **NOTE:** The endpoint IPs may not be loopback (`127.0.0.0/8`), link-local
>   (`169.254.0.0/16`), or link-local multicast (`224.0.0.0/24`). They cannot
>   be the cluster IPs of other Kubernetes services either because the
>   kube-proxy component doesn’t support virtual IPs as destination yet.

You can access this service by using `http://ext-elastic` inside the same namespace or by using `http://ext-elastic.default.svc.cluster.local` from a different namespace.

2. Create the ExternalName Service and specify a name of the external resource in the specification:

> An ExternalName service is a special case of service that does not
>   have selectors. It does not define any ports or Endpoints. Rather, it
>   serves as a way to return an alias to an external service residing
>   outside the cluster.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ext-elastic
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: my.external.elasticsearch.com
  ports:
  - port: 80
```

> When looking up the host my-service.prod.svc.CLUSTER, the cluster DNS
>   service will return a CNAME record with the value
>   my.database.example.com. Accessing such a service works in the same
>   way as others, with the only difference that the redirection happens
>   at the DNS level and no proxying or forwarding occurs. Should you
>   later decide to move your database into your cluster, you can start
>   its pods, add appropriate selectors or endpoints and change the
>   service type.

Check out another [article](https://akomljen.com/kubernetes-tips-part-1/) to see some more examples.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer. I will try this and see further,

Comment: I tried this as I have a similar scenario and it does work!